# hibernate not generating insert statement with certain column

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, hibernate-5.x

I have 3 entities interacting with each other as explained below.

```
Entity_A {
   @Id
   private String id;

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="a", orphanRemoval=true)
   private List<Entity_B> b;

   @OneToMany(cascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="a", orphanRemoval=true)
   private List<EntityRelationship_A_B> relationship;
}

@Embeddable
EntityRelationship_A_B_Id {
     @Column(name="a_id")
     private String a_id;

     @Column(name="b_id")
     private String b_id;

     @Column(name="relationship_id")
     private String relationship_id;
}

EntityRelationship_A_B {
   @EmbeddedId
   private EntityRelationship_A_B_Id id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumn="a_id", insertable=false, updateable=false)
   private Entity_A a;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="relationship", orphanremoval = true)
   private Entity_B b;
}

@Embeddable
Entity_B_Id {
   @Column(name="a_id")
   private String a_id;

   @Column(name="b_id")
   private String b_id;

   //std methods    
}

Entity_B {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Entity_B_Id id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumn = "a_id", insertable = false, updateable = false)
    private Entity_A a;

    @OneToOne(fetch = fetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumn="a_id", insertable=false, updateable=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumn="b_id", insertable=false, updateable=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="relationship_id", referencedColumn="relationship_id", insetable=false, updateable=false)
    private EntityRelationship_A_B relationship;

    // ....
}

ServiceImpl {
   save (...) {
        Manually populate and set Entity_B_Id into individual instance_A.instance_B
        Manually populate and set EntityRelationship_A_B_Id into individual instance_A.instance_A_B
        //...finally save the top level entity...
   }
}
```

Due to the nature of data, **same instance** of `Entity_B` **can't** be related to Both `Entity_A` and `EntityRelationship_A_B`.

With bi-directional references being implemented for owning sides, I can see `EntityRelationship_A_B` saves with proper values for `a_id, b_id, relationship_id`;

**But**  `Entity_B` always gets stored with `null` for `relationship_id`; in fact the insert statement for `Entity_B` never contains `relationship_id` column at all. However I can guarantee by looking into the runtime values that the `EntityRelationship_A_B` references are properly set `EntityRelationship_A_B.Entity_B`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're using insertable=false that means hibernate will ignore those attributes in insert statements

Comment: how can I populate relationship_id in Entity_B table?

Comment: setting the ´a_id´ value in ´id´ attribute (private Entity_B_Id id), as this entity has mapped the ´a_id´  this will be used in insert/update statements